# Maxima/minima/saddle?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives, maxima-minima

I was studying this function:
$$f(x)=x^8-2x^4y+y^3-y$$
and I had to compute maxima/minima/saddles. I found the minima by studying gradient and hessian of the function which are:
$$\nabla f(x,y)=(8x^7-8x^3y,3y^2-2x^4-1)$$
$$H_f(x,y)=\begin{bmatrix}56x^6-24x^2y & -8x^3 \\ -8x^3 & 6y \end{bmatrix}$$

from which we have that stationary points are: $(0, \pm \frac{1}{\sqrt 3}), (\pm 1,1)$. We have that, as the hessian is positive defined in $(\pm 1, 1)$, that these points are local minimas. 
Now the second derivative test fails for $(x,y)=(0, \pm \frac{1}{\sqrt 3})$ so what am I supposed to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second derivative test fails for $(x,y)=(0,\pm 1/\sqrt{3})$. Call one of these points $(a_x,a_y)$. I would try to do this: take $f$ and replace $x$ with $a_x+t \cos(s)$ and $y$ with $a_y+t \sin(s)$. So you have $f(x(t),y(t))$.. I will call this function just $f(t)$. Expand $f(t)$ in series: for the point $a_x=0$ and $a_y=1/\sqrt{3}$  I obtain:
$$
-(2/(3 \sqrt{3}))+\sqrt{3} \sin(s)^2 t^2  + \sin(s)^3 t^3 - (2 \cos(s)^4 t^4)/\sqrt{3}+O(t)^5
$$
In this way you see that the problem is for the direction $s=0$ (the $s=\pi$ is the same direction). Along this direction the first term that is non-zero is the fourth-order term, which is negative (so along the direction $s=0$ you have a maximum). For $s\neq0$, the first non-zero term is the second-order term, which is always positive.. so at the end I would call this a saddle point.

Comment: Okay, nice answer, I'll try. But the real problem is that I don't understand how you realize that you have to do something like this.. How do you realize that you should go in cosine/sine directions? Or how do you understand that there might be a problem in a specified direction?

Comment: Well, it's just a try, like the Hessian method. Given a point you can parametrize every straight line passing trough that point in this way: the parameter along the curve is $t$, for $t=0$ you sit on the point (this is why you just need to do an expansion near $t=0$.

Comment: You realize that the re is a problem along a direction because that direction (that choice of $s$) kills the first terms of the series expansion.. possibly the first two (at least), otherwise the Hessian method wouldn't fail.

Comment: Perfect explanation. Thanks. I need to practice a lot. ;)